# how to change one dropdown value by changing another dropdown

Tags: jquery

i have 2 drop down lists and I would like to make it so that when someone selects for example value        Abbeville from dropdown1, dropdown2 is automitacally changed to value Pie Chart. Is this possible using jquery?

```
<select id="county">
<option value="select" selected>Select</option>
<option value="Abbeville">Abbeville</option>
<option value="Aberdeen">Aberdeen</option>
</select>

<select id="ctype">
<option value="select" selected>Select</option>
<option value="pie">Pie Chart</option>
<option value="bar">Bar Chart</option>
<option value="line">Line Chart</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
$("#county").change(function(){ 
   $("#ctype").val($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: What you have tried man?

Comment: @JqueryKing : ok, that was harsh....people start learning too...you might know it all but not every knows everything....please keep that in mind!!

Comment: $("#county").change(function(){
    $("#ctype").val($(this).val());
});

Comment: @user1884538 : what your are looking for is called `cascading dropdown`, search for it using `jquery`

Comment: @NoobEditor - There are number of ways to do but the user not searching simply they post question in SO. It is user Lazyness

Comment: @JqueryKing : then close vote...end of story!

Comment: @NoobEditor - I already did

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.change()` function.

```js
$('#county').change(function(){
  $("#ctype option").eq($(this).find(':selected').index()).prop('selected',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="county">
<option value="select" selected>Select</option>
<option value="Abbeville">Abbeville</option>
<option value="Aberdeen">Aberdeen</option>
</select>

<select id="ctype">
<option value="select" selected>Select</option>
<option value="pie">Pie Chart</option>
<option value="bar">Bar Chart</option>
<option value="line">Line Chart</option>
</select>
```